# Error in starting openday light netconf testtool simulator

Tags: java, simulator, opendaylight

```
While starting open daylight netconf test tool simulator I am getting the following error:
```

"java -jar netconf-testtool-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar --device-count 2 --schemas-dir yangs/"

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:309)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)
at org.opendaylight.netconf.test.tool.TesttoolParameters.validate(TesttoolParameters.java:316)
at org.opendaylight.netconf.test.tool.Main.main(Main.java:58)
```

I can able to start it with some other yang files, but not with this specific yang files. What may be the issue causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source code:

```
final Matcher matcher = YANG_FILENAME_PATTERN.matcher(file.getName());
if (!matcher.matches()) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (!DATE_PATTERN.matcher(line).find()) {  <--- Line 316
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

It's trying to ensure the yang file has a revision date. If it's not in the yang file name, then it opens the file and searches for a revision date. It blows up b/c it reaches the EOF without finding it. That's my take from reading the source - assuming I'm correct then either rename the offending file with a valid revision or add a revision statement to the yang.